# 'No such table' SQL-Alchemy Error with Flask-Admin

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm trying to configure flask admin to provide an interface for the models in different blueprints.

`app/__init__.py`

```
def configure_extensions(app):
    # flask-sqlalchemy
    from .extensions import db
    db.init_app(app)
    # flask-admin
    configure_admin(app, db)

def configure_admin(app, db):
    from .extensions import admin
    from .admin import views
    from recipes.models import Recipe
    admin.add_view(views.ModelView(Recipe, db.session))
    admin.init_app(app)
```

app/extensions.py

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

from flask.ext.admin import Admin
admin = Admin()
```

The admin home page works fine, and shows the registered views. But when I try to access a view I get *OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table*

Comment: Did you create your database? You need to call `db.create_all()` for the tables to be created.

Comment: I created the database with an Alembic migration. Just to try, I added db.create_all() just after db.init_app(app), and I got a Runtime Error, application not registered on db instance

Comment: Do the tables exist in the database or not? Use a db administration tool to check. If they don't, then you need to ask a different question. I'm strongly inclined to believe the error message you get from SQLAlchemy, the tables are likely not there.

Comment: Are you sure the migration succeeded? SQLAlchemy will fail with that error if the table doesn't exist, but also if a column you have in your code doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: Yes the database is there, I can access it and see the tables with a desktop client...

Comment: This exception is coming from SQLAlchemy - make sure your connection string is correct, your user can access the database and so on. Try running simple query against table in question too.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the database is there, that you're connecting to the correct database and that the tables' schema matches exactly what's in the code? As I said, you'll also see that error even if there's a table with that name but some column is missing.